# Populating online PDFForm opened in adobe plugin via vba

Tags: vba, pdf, plugins, adobe

I am looking for help for a project.
I'm trying to automate pdfform filling with excel table data. Have no problems filling it when the pdf is locally saved, but the form I want to work with **is loaded on the web page via adobe plugin.**

I've observed in the task manager that when the pdfform loads process **Adobe.Broker** starts running.
So I believe this is what I should connect to, but still couldn't figure it out.

The problem is that I can`t download the pdf and upload it. I should work only in the web pdf form.

I know I can send keys via stuff like Autoit and etc., but trying to avoid this. Oh, one more thing, I **must** use IE only, so Selenium is not an option, thou I don't know if it can solve my problem.

I cannot provide link to the pdfform, because it is loaded via e-signature.

I've read that it is impossible to connect to the plugin /addon/, is this true?
I prefer using vba, cause I'm familiar with it, but I am open to any languages.

Would appreciate any answers, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'll say is... don't. The plug-in for IE may stop working at any time, it's not longer a recommended method of displaying PDF in the browser. If you can't rearchitect your environment, I suspect that the Reader is in Safe Mode which is the default when in the browser. If you want to communicate with the Reader via VBA, you'll need to turn off Enhanced Security in the Reader preferences. I DO NOT RECOMMEND DOING THIS!!!! Or you can put the PDF in a Trusted domain which you also define in the preferences. Once you're able to communicate with the PDF via VBA, you can set the field values with code similar to below.

```
Set Field = Fields("foo")
Field.Value = "bar"
```